# Unable to create voice message in audio file using Ionic's Media plugin

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic4

I have chat component in my app and I'm trying to add sending voice messages (like WhatsApp) feature. I'm using Ionic's Media plugin and MediaObject type. The app is intended for Android and iOS. Currently, I'm testing on Android and haven't got any luck!

I tried the code below to create a MediaObject and store the recorded audio in it. And if the user clicks the button again, I'd like to stop the recording. It's working because I get the logs on the console, but `getDuration()` returns -1!

```
startRecording() {
if (!this.recording) {
      console.log('Started Recording');
      this.recording = true;
      this.fileName = Date.now();
      this.audio = this.media.create(`../../../../assets/chat/${this.fileName}.m4a`);
      this.audio.startRecord();
      this.listenToAudioEvents();
     } else {
      this.stopRecording();
    }
}

stopRecording() {
    this.audio.stopRecord();
    console.log(this.audio);
    this.recording = false;
    this.audioReady = true;
    this.audio.getDuration();
    console.log('Audio Duration: ' + this.audio.getDuration());
  }
```

I'd like to stop recording when `stopRecording()` is invoked and retain the audio file so I can upload it. Also, I'm not really sure where the file would actually be stored on Android nor iOS.

Comment: so a lot of those methods I suppose should be async and would accept a callback functions whose argument should be the recording? anyway did you try to scout github of this plugin for examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the issue was the location where I was saving the generated media file. First of all, I needed to use Ionic Native's [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file) plugin. And then create the media file at `File.tempDirectory` for iOS and at `File.externalDataDirectory` for Android:

```
if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        await this.file.createFile(this.file.tempDirectory, this.fileName, true);
        this.filePath =  this.file.tempDirectory + this.fileName;
        this.audio = this.media.create(this.file.tempDirectory.replace(/^file:\/\//, '') + this.fileName);
      } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
        this.filePath = this.file.externalDataDirectory + this.fileName;
        this.audio = this.media.create(this.filePath);
      }
      this.audio.startRecord();
```

It is also important to note the extra steps for iOS, as outlined [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media) at the bottom of the page. And then I was able to access the blob like this:

```
this.file.readAsDataURL(this.filePath.replace(this.fileName, ''), this.fileName).then(blob => {
   console.log(blob);
}
```

Comment: thank you for this. it was so annoying to figure this out!